# CSS/JS/HTML/Jquery etc maker/plugin/teacher slideshow?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, slideshow, html

I want to add picture + caption slideshow to my website. But I couldn't find something that will fit my goal. I'm looking for:

1. Buttons/bullets which on hover show little image
2. Change size to the window screen and the screen size(not have to be on minimize just on load)
3. Auto change
4. Animation (don't care which one as long as it nice)
5. Clean look
6. Buttons: Next previous pause
7. When hovering the arrows show the next prev picture

Like the title says don't care about what to use for it and don't care if I need to do it alone with plugin or use a demo teacher or something documented else.

If it has most of the thing above it will be nice does not have to be all of them.I need to be able to read and understand the code so I prefer CSS3 slideshows or documented ones